# How do I omit lines that contain Unicode NULL (U+0000)?

Tags: regex, perl, unicode, null, nul

I am reading a file and am wondering how to skip lines that have Unicode NULL, [U+0000](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0000/index.htm)? I have tried everything below, but none works:

- `if($line)`
- `chomp($line)`
- `$line =~ s/\s*$//g;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your list of "everything" does not seem to include the obvious `$line =~ m/\000/`.

Answer (score 2):

Perl strings can contain arbitrary data, including NUL characters.  Your `if` only checks for true or false (where `""` and `"0"` are the two false strings, everything else being true including a string containing a single NUL "\x00").  Your `chomp` only removes the line separator, not NULs.  A NUL character is not whitespace, so doesn't match `\s`.

You can explicitly match a NUL character by specifying it in a regex using octal or hex notation (`"\000"` or `"\x00"`, respectively).

Answer (score 2):

Because you asked about Unicode NULL (identical to ASCII NUL when encoded in [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)), let’s use the `\N{U+...}` form, described in the [perlunicode documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html#Effects-of-Character-Semantics).

> Unicode characters can also be added to a string by using the `\N{U+...}` notation.  The Unicode code for the desired character, in hexadecimal, should be placed in the braces, after the `U`. For instance, a smiley face is `\N{U+263A}`.

You can also match against `\N{U+...}` in regexes. See below.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $contents =
  "line 1\n" .
  "\N{U+0000}\n" .
  "foo\N{U+0000}bar\n" .
  "baz\N{U+0000}\n" .
  "\N{U+0000}quux\n" .
  "last\n";

open my $fh, "<", \$contents or die "$0: open: $!";

while (defined(my $line = <$fh>)) {
  next if $line =~ /\N{U+0000}/;
  print $line;
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./filter-nulls
line 1
last
```